# How do I run a sql file of inserts through docker run?

Tags: docker, psql, docker-run, docker-exec

Given a file with a SQL insert:

```
INSERT INTO countries (id, country_code, name)
VALUES
    (1, 'AF', 'Afghanistan'),
    (2, 'AL', 'Albania');
```

I would like to run the file by using the `docker run` command on a container that is running postgres.

I've tried this:

```
docker run -e domain="192.168.99.100" pg /bin/bash -c "psql -d whiteboard_api -a -f inserts_into_countries_table.sql"
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

you can see my image is pg:

```
capistrano:whiteboard_v2 jzollars$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
6b500bec9210        bbb                 "/usr/bin/supervisord"   4 weeks ago         Up 4 weeks          0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp       distracted_raman
c1e88f2695f5        wh                  "/usr/bin/supervisord"   4 weeks ago         Up 4 weeks          0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp   high_einstein
7e383e99bdc3        pg                  "/usr/lib/postgresql/"   4 weeks ago         Up 4 weeks          0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp   pg_test
```

How can I load this file and run it in a docker container using `docker run`?

Comment: could you share your `pg` image Dockerfile?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

to execute commands against a running container use [docker exec](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/).

to copy a file (ex: dump.sql) into a container, use [docker cp](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/)

So your approach might look something like this:

```
docker cp ./dump.sql pg_test:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/dump.sql
docker exec -u postgres pg_test psql postgres postgres -f docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/dump.sql
```

here it is in generic form:

```
docker cp ./localfile.sql containername:/container/path/file.sql
docker exec -u postgresuser containername psql dbname postgresuser -f /container/path/file.sql
```

And note that if you need to seed your database every time it is run, the folder `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` does [have special significance](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/2c72165e4f9dc66a61998111f69b5eba0b6b71f4/9.5/docker-entrypoint.sh#L77), if you're using the  [offical postgres image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/)

Comment: Thanks this was a great answer, especially like the "generic form"

Comment: is there away to do this without copying the file into the container?

Comment: I did some looking round and I couldn't find anyway to do it without copying the file into the docker container, if anyone finds a way please post the answer

Comment: @MaxCarroll, you can mount your file into the container, rather than explicitely copying it, using the _volume_ flag: `docker run -v ./dump.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/dump.sql pg_test`

Answer (score 92):

You can run a sql command file against a running postgres container via the one liner

```
cat ./query.sql | docker exec -i <container-name> psql -U <user> -d <database>
```

without having to copy the file from your host machine to the container.

Comment: This worked for me. I was hesitant to use the other answers since they all use multiple lines or would store the file on the docker instance. I think this is the best answer for my use case since it just executes the script and nothing else.

Comment: Based on this answer I expected this to work as well, and it did. Thanks. `echo SELECT * FROM table; | docker exec -i postgresdb psql -U user -d db`

Comment: Seems to work only when psql is run on the db in the docker container. Won't run on a "remote" db. Mentioned this because I only want to use the psql command of the docker container to run an SQL on another db.

Comment: Ok. Figured out how to do it:

echo "select count(*) from ..." | docker exec -i postgres-12.3  sh -c "export PGPASSWORD=<pwd> && psql -U <user> -h <ip> -p 5432 -d <db>"

Thanks for the answer. It helped.

Answer (score 9):

With the official Docker image of PostgreSQL, [code_monk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34688465/how-do-i-run-a-sql-file-of-inserts-through-docker-run/34688994#34688994) does not work for me. 
I arrive to this solution:

```
docker exec -it <container-name> psql -U <DB_USER> -d <DB_NAME> -f /file.sql
```

Comment: is the /file.sql inside the container or is it on the host, i tried this but it says file not found im wondering if its looking for the file in the container instead of the host?

Comment: The file must be in the container. You can copy it with `docker cp`

Answer (score 1):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -e

FUN_SQL2="
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_event(text)
  RETURNS integer AS
\\\\$BODY\\\\$
DECLARE ret INTEGER;
begin
select $1 into ret;
RETURN ret;

end;
\\\\$BODY\\\\$
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE
  COST 100;
"

# add function to DB
docker exec -it db_container sh -c "psql -U postgres -d db_name -c \"$FUN_SQL2\" ";
```

Comment: \\\$BODY\\\   
must contain 3 \\\

Answer (score 1):

Just in case, if you also want to ssh, here is one liner with script/sql

#!/bin/bash

ssh -tt -i .ssh/local.pem username@remotehost docker exec -ti docker-container /usr/bin/psql postgresql://user:password@dbhost:port/dbname -f sqlscript_on_docker

ssh -tt -i .ssh/local.pem username@remotehost docker exec -ti docker-container /usr/bin/psql postgresql://user:password@dbhost:port/dbname -c \"select \* from table\”